# is there any Recommendations plugin in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, plugins, drupal-modules, drupal-7, recommendation-engine

I am implementing the recommendations for my website using drupal 7.  This recommendations is the one in which if i check out any books, then it also shows me some other books of the category which are good.  Is there any such plugins available in drupal 7 if not then is it possible to code recommendations in drupal??

Thanks,
     Aby

Answer (score 0):

ImageCache now is part of the core

Answer (score -2):

You can use this modules in every project:

Views, Token, Pathauto, IMCE, FileField Sources, Google Analytics, Chaos tool suite, Backup and Migrate, XML sitemap, Devel, Panels, Global Redirect, CKEditor - WYSIWYG HTML editor, 
External Links, Flag, Quick Tabs, Login Destination, Colorbox, Context, Workbench, ImageCache, Actions, Social Share, Administration menu, Advanced help